# textx Grammar, Use Whitespace as Repetition Modifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, textx

I'm trying to write a parser for input files used by [Fire Dynamics Simulator](https://pages.nist.gov/fds-smv/) using [`textx`](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/). For the most part, ignoring the whitespace is perfect as most parameters and values should be separated by commas. However, it is acceptable to [ignore the comma at the end of a parameter](https://github.com/firemodels/fds/blob/master/Verification/Fires/room_fire.fds#L9) and it appears that the program also will look past [missing comma in the value list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firemodels/fds/master/Validation/Crown_Fires/FDS_Input_Files/Heil_post_13ms.fds).

I've trimmed down the grammar definition for this question, but the code below shows that there are 2 records in `data` which start with `&` and end with `/`. Each record has two parameters. The first one has some string values while the second record has numeric values. This code works well.

```py
import textx

def test_parse_mesh(model):
    expected = {
        'XB': [0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3.0],
        'IJK': [50, 40, 30],
    }
    parsed = {
        param.name: param.value
        for param in model.records[1].parameters
    }
    assert expected == parsed

grammar = """
Model: records*=Record;
Record: /^&/ namelist=ID parameters*=Parameter[','] '/';
Parameter: name=ID '=' value+=Value[','];
Value: (NUMBER | STRING);
"""

data = """
&HEAD CHID='Some Value', TITLE='another string'/
&MESH IJK = 50,40,30,
      XB  = 0.0,5.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,3.0/
"""

mm = textx.metamodel_from_str(grammar)
model = mm.model_from_str(data)
test_parse_mesh(model)
```

However, I want to be able to modify the `grammar` to be able to parse the following version of `data`:

```py
data = """
&HEAD CHID='Some Value', TITLE='another string'/
&MESH IJK = 50 40 30
      XB  = 0.0 5.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 3.0/
"""
```

I've looked at [repetition modifiers](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#repetition-modifiers) and was able to get the following to work, but was unable to get it to work in the larger grammar definition. I also tried to alter the [parser configuration](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/parser_config/#whitespace-handling), but was unable to get that to work properly.

```py
grammar = """
Record[noskipws]: parameters*=Parameter[/,|\s+/];
Parameter[noskipws]: /\s*/ name=ID /\s*=\s*/ value+=NUMBER[/,|\s+/];
"""

data = """
IJK = 50 40 30 
XB = 0 5 0 4 0 3
"""

mm = textx.metamodel_from_str(grammar)
model = mm.model_from_str(data)

expected = {'XB': [0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3.0], 'IJK': [50, 40, 30]}
assert {param.name: param.value for param in model.parameters} == expected
```

How can I modify the grammar at the top to correctly parse the second version of `data` where there are no commas? I'll accept an answer that just gets it to work with [one parameter per line](https://github.com/firemodels/fds/blob/master/Verification/Fires/room_fire.fds#L9), but ideally would be able to handle the missing comma in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your post I though the solution should be a simple optional match for separator like:

```
Model: records*=Record;
Record: /^&/ namelist=ID parameters*=Parameter[/,?/] '/';
Parameter: name=ID '=' value+=Value[/,?/];
Value: NUMBER | STRING;
```

But, it didn't work. After some debug output investigation I noticed that optional separator match `,?` although successful on places where comma was absent would terminate repetition match. The bug was in Arpeggio. I just made a fix. It is available on the `master` branch so please install from GitHub for now. I will be releasing a new version of Arpeggio soon. With the provided bugfix the above grammar works correctly. You can even mix and match, use separator just on some places, like e.g.:

```
&HEAD CHID='Some Value' TITLE='another string'/
&MESH IJK = 50 40, 30,
      XB  = 0.0 5.0, 0.0 4.0 0.0 3.0/
```

**Edit [2021-04-25]:** Arpeggio 1.10.2 is released with the fix mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I love the `/,?/` syntax! that looks so nice and clean. Glad to know I wasn't missing something in the textx documentation. Thanks for monitoring the textx tag.

Comment: You are welcome. FYI, that syntax in between `/../` is standard Python regex syntax so everything you use from `re` module should work here. Not only for separators but for any Regex match.

Comment: @Cohan Bugfix release of Arpeggio is out so you can install as usual.